# Install Ubuntu from scratch

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have windows installed on my 500 GB hard disk which contains of 5 partitions. One for system drive and rest four for data. I want to format and remove all the 5 partitions and convert that to following three partitions:

1. 30 GB Ubuntu Gnome 13.04.
2. 2 GB Linux - Swap.
3. 50 GB Windows 7.
4. Rest windows ntfs partitions.

I have a bootable Windows 7 Ultimate DVD, a bootable Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 flash Drive. I don't wish to backup any data that I have I want to remove all the partition and install both the OS from scratch. I read many articles but each one has a different method some suggesting to use GParted, and some others to install Ubuntu first and then Windows etc.

Please suggest me a **step by step detailed** guide or reference to complete the task.

Comment: The installer's partitioner should be fine for this.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PART 1

Step 1.) Boot from the Ubuntu Gnome Flash Drive.

When booted go to the application Gparted.
(Click on the dash icon and search for Gparted in the applications).
Gparted is the best and most simple partition editor available.

Step 2.)In Gparted right click on each partition and click on delete, till you have deleted all the partitons and have left only 1 single block of unallocated space( around 460 gb it will be).

Step 3.)Now you are ready to partition. Right Click on the unallocated space, select new.
Create your desired partitions by.
to create 30 gb ubuntu partition: right click on unallocated space then new.

size- 30720 mb
type- ext4
(rest all options as is)

for swap-
size - 2048 mb
type-
linux swap

i suggest you allocate atleast 60 gb for windows 7
so 
size-61440
type-ntfs

right click on left unallocated space,
type-ntfs
size - as is is

after that click on the apply button in the menu bar to save the changes.
it will then write the partitions and display successful.
---end part 1---

PART 2-

partitioning is done.
Now you are ready to install the OS.
First install Windows.
Steps-
Boot from the windows 7 DVD.
Click on install.
Then Custom install.
Here select your 60gb NTFS partiton that you have earlier created and install to it.
After successfully installing, reboot and see if windows 7 is working fine.

--end part 2--

PART 3

Now that your windows is installed its time to install ubuntu.

Boot from the ubuntu gnome 13.04 usb

Click on the install option on the desktop.

When it comes to the option 
"Install Ubuntu 13.04"
It would Display 2 options-
1. Install Ubuntu (automatic)
2.Something Else

CHOOSE something else.
choosing it would bring you to the Gparted partition editor.
Here the swap partition will be detected automatically.
Right click on your 30 gb ext4 partiton, click on edit, and set mount point as /

Verify thats everthing is correct and click on install

THATS It.
If you have any problems let us know..

Answer (score 0):

Boot the live CD and enter the installer.

When prompted with the partition type, select "Something else", likely labeled with a gear icon.

Now, you should have a list of partitions. Select your `/dev/sda` disk(not `/dev/sda1` with the number) and click <kbd>New partition table</kbd>. Make it MBR or GPT as per your preference. MBR should be fine.

Now, let's create the partitions.

Select the free space and click the "add" button. You'll want to create an EXT4 partition of 30,000 MB and with the mount point `/`. This is a forward slash. Check the box to format the partition if it is unchecked.

Then, create a new partition in the same manner with the type "Swap space" and size of 2048 MB.

Do the same with an NTFS partition sans mount point. No mount point necessary.

Create an NTFS partition for data with the default size. No mount point necessary.

Brew coffee.

Install Ubuntu.

Install Windows. GRUB will be broken. Grab your live CD and follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/54298) to repair grub.

Reboot.

Profit.

Comment: I'm not getting any option for MBR or GPT as you mentioned in your third point. Also will it be good to create the 2 windows ntfs partition during the Something Else part only or should I do that in the windows installation section?

Comment: @meteors DO all of this in the Ubuntu installation; if there is no mbr/gpt just skip that selection.