# how to Installing

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows-7

I am currently running windows 7 32bit and want to replace with ubuntu, how would one go about doing so (not that tecie so a step by step would be nice)? also could I revert back if needed?(on a laptop hp)

thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu from scratch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/331694/install-ubuntu-from-scratch)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Did you read that ?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

It give you all the information you could need. And if you think it isn't detailed enough, just try "Install Ubuntu" on google and you will find all the tutorials you could dream of.

It's possible to reinstall Windows after that, but you will need an installation CD and a licence.

It's is possible to have more than a single OS in your computer too, with dual-boot.

Have a nice evening,

Damien.